# Accessing fields of particular layer

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, layers

I am trying to access the fields which I can see in this particular [layer](http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/911CallsHotspot/MapServer/jobs/jef3fd04155ce410386cc7f64ebad694d/0). I am able to see that it has fields but fetching the values in those fields is something that I am unable to do. Is there someway to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the REST interface 'Query', scroll to bottom of page that you gave, here is a query for OBJECTID > 0, shows 98 records.

Where field: OBJECTID > 0
Outfields: *

http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/911CallsHotspot/MapServer/jobs/jef3fd04155ce410386cc7f64ebad694d/0/query?where=OBJECTID+%3E+0&text=&objectIds=&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&relationParam=&outFields=*&returnGeometry=true&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&gdbVersion=&returnDistinctValues=false&f=html

In javascript, do something like this...

```
    var selectQuery = new esri.tasks.Query();
    selectQuery.where = "OBJECTID > 0";
    selectQuery.outFields = ["*"];
    var queryTask = new esri.tasks.QueryTask("http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/911CallsHotspot/MapServer/jobs/jef3fd04155ce410386cc7f64ebad694d");
    queryTask.execute(selectQuery, function (features) {
        //do something with features returned
    });
```

Comment: what is it that I need to enter for the query? query in `queryTask.selectQuery(query, function (features) {//code here});`

Comment: edited above: queryTask.execute(selectQuery, function(...

Comment: is it possible to replicate the same Map Service in arcserver 10.03? I am trying to fetch the layer info like the example link you posted but it returns an error on ArcServer 10

Comment: Not sure what you mean about replicating. However, this sample service in question is actually paired with a geoprocessing service. The map service is the result of the geoprocessing service. You use a jobID to access it. It is deleted by defaut in 6 hours. Check out help here http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/About_result_map_services_in_REST_applications/0154000005v3000000/

Comment: exactly this is on 10.1 but I am not able to create the same in 10. When I try to access the map server created by geoprocessing service in 10 it gives an error.

Answer (score 2):

Scoll to the bottom of the page you gave and click "Query". To return all features in the layer, enter "0=0" in the top text box (labeled "Where:"). "0=0" is a true condition for all features. Leave all the other text boxes blank and press the "Query (GET)" button at the bottom of the form.

I recommend the JavaScript answer from awesomo, but if you want to only get certain fields, replace the "*" in

```
    selectQuery.outFields = ["*"];
```

with the field headings you want to work with. If you only want to return CALL_TYPE, CITY, and Date, the JavaScript would be

```
    selectQuery.outFields = ["CALL_TYPE", "CITY", "Date"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to get objects from this particular layer?

Your layer has /query endpoint, where you can query for objects on your layer [Layer 0: Query](http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/911CallsHotspot/MapServer/jobs/jef3fd04155ce410386cc7f64ebad694d/0/query)

On this layer there is 98 objects. One sample object is [OBJECTID:6](http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/911CallsHotspot/MapServer/jobs/jef3fd04155ce410386cc7f64ebad694d/0/6)